# Colouring and bending the edges of a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have the edges of the tree to be have an S-shaped bend as well as colour the top edge of a node with one colour and the bottom with another. I can think of two possible solutions: the first (inspired from [Dmitrii Volosnykh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16301/167081) solution) bends the arrows as expected but doesn't support multi colours. This is found in `customEdge`. The second is redrawing the paths using `edge from parent path`. I don't how to proceed. The labels are important in this situation. I would appreciate a solution using the Ti*k*Z's `tree` library rather than `forest` or `tikz-qtree` packages.

[image: Current output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=8em, level distance=6em},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=4em, level distance=6em},
    topLabelStyle/.style={
        draw=red,
        every node/.style={
            fill=white, inner sep=4pt, text=red, draw=none
          },
      },
    bottomLabelStyle/.style={
        draw=blue,
        every node/.style={
            fill=white, inner sep=4pt, text=blue
          },
      },
    % Either allow customEdge to alternate between the two colours or fix 
    % edge from parent path so that the paths matches the grays ones.
    edge from parent/.style={customEdge,  -Latex},
    customEdge/.code={
        \draw [thick, gray, -Latex] (\tikzparentnode.east) to[looseness = 0.5, out=0,in=-180,]
        (\tikzchildnode.west);
      },
    edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode.east) .. controls +(90:1) and +(180:1) .. (\tikzchildnode.west)
      },
  ]
  \node {root}[grow'=right]
  child {
      node {1}
      child {
          node {3} edge from parent[topLabelStyle] node[] {c}
        }
      child {
          node {4} edge from parent[bottomLabelStyle] node[] {d}
        }
      edge from parent[topLabelStyle] node[] {a}
    }
  child {
      node {2}
      child {
          node {5} edge from parent[topLabelStyle] node[] {e}
        }
      child {
          node {6} edge from parent[bottomLabelStyle] node[] {f}
        }
      edge from parent[bottomLabelStyle] node[] {b}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your image doesn't show any nodes using different colours for the top and bottom, does it? Note this would be much easier in `forest`. Any particular reason you don't like it?

Comment: @cfr, the `forest` package is fantastic and, as you mentioned, easier to use (and even better documentation in my opinion with lots of examples). I just started typesetting trees in LaTeX and wanted to learn how to complete the task using `tikz` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to almost do it. Basic differences to the code you posted:

- for some reason the `code` section blocked passing style parameters
- doing a little less I removed those parts and kind of rebuilt your code
- `edge from parent/.style={draw,red,->},` is now default style AND, whenever needed, the downward pathes are overwritten, see code below
- in the path using `(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)` would do with straight lines, while replacing `--` with `to [out=0,in=180]` seems to ignore the `pos`-parameter, which places the node/label along said path
- a modification of your `controls` statement did the job:
- `.. controls +(0:.5) and +(180:.5) ..` now puts a reference point right of the parent and left of the child, which creates the s-shape
- however, the approach seems to conflict with placing a label between root and its children
- I suggest to insert a `child`, called root, which should work fine with the approach shown, AND make the `\node` itself invisible, i.e. use empty text `\node {} ...`
- some children had to become black again to avoid colored node texts, which you certainly can handle by `every` in the style section
- finally, I changed indenting to better see which units belong together (*defensive or preventive programming*)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=8em, level distance=6em},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=4em, level distance=6em},
    edge from parent/.style={draw,red,->},% default style
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) 
                            .. controls +(0:.5) and +(180:.5) ..
                           (\tikzchildnode.west)
%           (\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)
    },
    >={Stealth},
    lbl/.style={pos=0.5,fill=white},
    dwn/.style={blue},
  ]
  \node {root}[grow'=right]
      child{
          node {1}
          child{
               node {3} edge from parent node[lbl] {c}
          }
          child{
              node {4}  edge from parent[dwn] node[lbl] {d}
          } 
      }
      child{
          node {2} edge from parent[blue]% to be replaced by dwn
          child[black]{
              node {5}edge from parent node[lbl] {e}
          }
          child[black]{
              node {6} edge from parent[dwn] node[lbl] {f}
          }
      }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted!